# Is it possible to set Pane's recoures inside of the controller class?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

Currently, when I want to set a translation bundle to the particular Pane, I have to do it before loading. Let's consider a simple example:

Bundle_en.properties

```
key=Sample Text
```

MainApplication.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.Bundle",new Locale("en","EN")));
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Now I can use names from the inside of the bundle:

sample.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <Label text="%key"/>
</GridPane>
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to move the process of setting the resources to the initialize() method inside the controller?

Controller.java

```
public class Controller {
  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    // setting resources here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you have two ways in i18n your application. From fxml docs:

> The content of an FXML file can be localized as the file is read. For
>   example, if an FXML file is loaded using the en_US locale, then it
>   produces the string "First Name" for a label based on the following
>   resource string:
>
> `<Label text="%firstName"/>`
>
> If the locale **is changed** to fr_FR **and** the FXML file is reloaded, then
>   the label shows "Prénom."

On the other hand, you may change values from java code:

> The same is not true for Java code, because you must manually update
>   the content of every element of your user interface by obtaining a
>   reference to it and calling the appropriate setter (such as
>   setText()).

Also ResourceBundle is an input parameter of initialize method in Initializable interface, it is used during loading fxml file.

So i don't think that it is possible to set resources inside initialize method. You probably may load resources from Controller later and use them from java code. Not sure that it's best solution for large applications.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the [fx:root](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/custom_control.htm#BABDAAHE) construct and define the fxml and properties file per custom control.

If you like to follow some simple naming conventions you could use a utility class I wrote to load the the fxml file:

```
import org.drombler.commons.fx.fxml.FXMLLoaders;  
...  

public class MyPane extends SomePane {  

    public MyPane() {  
        FXMLLoaders.loadRoot(this);  
    }  

    ...  
}
```

You can read more about this in my [blog](http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2015/03/drombler-commons-conventions-to.html).